# DataType to store control type Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying a simple project to create my own (very basic) data binding.

I have a class FIELD_DESCRIPTOR which stores meta information about a database column.  There will be a further class FIELD which represents the actual field, which will contain a reference to its corresponding FIELD_DESCRIPTOR class.

I am getting stuck in 2 places.

First, I need to have a property in the FIELD_DESCRIPTOR class that stores what kind of Windows Forms control the field is mapped to at the front end. for e.g. I need a property, say, MAPPED_CONTROL_TYPE.  And I should be able to store either TextBox, ComboBox etc in this property.  Should I just use a string property and be done with it ? Or is there a better way ?  Ideally, I'd like to use some kind of enumeration of control types.

Secondly, I need to store a reference / handle to the actual control the field it mapped to.  (I think I can do this by passing a reference of the actual control on the form.)

How do I implement this ? What kind of dataType should be used to define this property ?

(Using .Net 3.5, No WPF)

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, I need to have a property in the FIELD_DESCRIPTOR class that
>   stores what kind of Windows Forms control the field is mapped to at
>   the front end. for e.g. I need a property, say, MAPPED_CONTROL_TYPE.
>   And I should be able to store either TextBox, ComboBox etc in this
>   property. Should I just use a string property and be done with it ? Or
>   is there a better way ? Ideally, I'd like to use some kind of
>   enumeration of control types.

The fully qualified type name springs to mind, e.g. System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.  This should be unique, and could always be used for dynamic creation if needed.

> Secondly, I need to store a reference / handle to the actual control
>   the field it mapped to. (I think I can do this by passing a reference
>   of the actual control on the form.)

You could indeed store the reference using a type such as System.Windows.Forms.Control.  If you do, be carefult that you don't create a memory leak.  i.e. When you control is no longer needed, you should no longer hold its reference in your lookup otherwise you will stop it being disposed.

Comment: Thx @Justin, How do I define the datatype this property ? System.Windows.Forms.TextBox will be the value in the property.  I get that. What will the property definition look like ?     string MAPPED_CONTROL_TYPE ?

Comment: I think string is fine, I cannot think of a better way without making life harder.

Comment: Thx@Justin.  I'll go with string then.  I thought there would be some C# type to store the control type.

Comment: A type could be stored as System.Type, but that would mean constructing individual System.Type instances, which imo would be a bit of a waste of resources.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  I decided to use an enum with the different type of controls and a simple int value for each type of control. Seemed a bit better than string.

Comment: Just remembered to mark my query as answered and your solution helpful.  Thx again.